# Tortoise SVN Commit Error Sending Content

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

i am trying to commit my powerpoint presentation for uni. I can commit small files < 1 MB but if i try to commit my presentation ( around 10 MB ), it adds all the stuff and when it hangs up saying Sending Content... .

Just in case I didnt wait long enough, I was at 27 MB transferred.. And the file has 10MB. So, how is that even possible?

greetz

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are using up-to-date TortoiseSVN version. Right now it is TortoiseSVN 1.9. Grab it at https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html
2. Disable you antivirus and try again. Add Subversion-related resources to exclusion list of the antivirus.
3. Contact your SVN server admin. They should ensure that the server in on up-to-date Subversion 1.9 or at least 1.8 version.